# can we upload tiff image on top of cesium map?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to upload png and tiff images but unable to load on top of cesium.Is there any possibility to load png and tiff images at some location with the help of wkt data?

Answer (score 0):

so this is the way you can add imagery on cesium

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
imageryProvider : Cesium.createWorldImagery({
    style : Cesium.IonWorldImageryStyle.AERIAL_WITH_LABELS
}),
baseLayerPicker : false
});
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
url : '../images/Cesium_Logo_overlay.png',
rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-75.0, 28.0, -67.0, 29.75)
}));
```

https://cesium.com/docs/tutorials/imagery-layers/ is the link for imagery on cesium give it a look

Comment: This is helpful for loading the images.But is there any possibility to load the tiff image at certain coordinates?like in certain wkt data?

Answer (score 0):

In short the browser does the loading of the images not the cesium and browsers dont support the tiff imagery you can utilize the TMS(tile mapping service) to convert the tiff into tiles and show them. Detailed Discussion in this link
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/cesium-dev/tiff|sort:date/cesium-dev/1pzd9liKgqg/a4V1DtKX_yQJ